# How do I get collision and animation to work in my 2d platformer?

Tags: java, animation, collision-detection

I was hoping to get some help with my collision detection/movement, It is working but buggy.
I cant reproduce the bugs with the collision detection/movement consistently. The player just sometimes cant move in certain directions, I also can't reproduce getting unstuck it just seems to start letting you move again for no reason. gravity doesn't always take effect when it should and sometimes you can get stuck in the wall. The code is below.

I also wanted to hear any suggestions on how I should implement animation(for example playing a walking animation while moving.) into the game. I have gotten one animation to work but it was messy and used Timer(); and I wanted to find a better way of doing it. any advice is appreciated.

I am coding the game in java using eclipse for learning purposes so I'm not looking for a 2d game engine.

Here is all of the code.

MarioLikeGame.java

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MarioLikeGame extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{
    private static Graphics graphics;
    private Image image;
    private static boolean running = true;
    private static Player player = new Player(4 * 32, 6 * 32 + 24,                             
    "images/playerStill.png", "images/playerWalking.png");
    private static PlayingBoard board = new PlayingBoard(player);
    private static ReadLevelFile readLevel = new ReadLevelFile();
    private static boolean scrollingRight = false;//To let player know to stop moving
    private static boolean scrollingLeft = false;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MarioLikeGame();
        readLevel.openFile();
        readLevel.readFile(board);
        readLevel.closeFile();
        gameLoop();
    }

    public MarioLikeGame()
    {
        setTitle("SideSCroIIer");
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(448, 320 + 24);// 32*32 tiles 14 wide  10 high
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        image = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        graphics = image.getGraphics();

        paintComponent(graphics);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {   
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        for(int row = 0; row < board.gameTiles.length; row++)
        {
            for(int column = 0; column < board.gameTiles[row].length; column++)
            {
                board.gameTiles[row][column].draw(g);
            }
        }

        player.draw(g);

    }

    public static void gameLoop()
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long cumTime = startTime;

        while(running)
        {
            long timePassed = System.currentTimeMillis() - cumTime;
            cumTime += timePassed;

            checkForCollision(timePassed);

            player.checkForPlayerMovement(timePassed, scrollingRight, scrollingLeft);
            board.checkForScroll(timePassed);

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}

        }
    }

    public static void checkForCollision(long timePassed)
    {
        //scroll if player tries to walk to the edge of the screen
        //check for scrollingRight
        if(player.xPos + 31 >= 11 * 32)
        {

            board.setScrollingRight(true);
            scrollingRight = true;


        }

        if(player.xPos + 31 < 11 * 32)
        {
            board.setScrollingRight(false);
            scrollingRight = false;
        }
        //Make sure to not scroll everything off screen
        //stop scrolling when the right walls right side is at the ride side of
             the screen
        if(board.gameTiles[board.gameTiles.length -1][0].xPos + 31 <= 448)
        {
            board.setScrollingRight(false);
            scrollingRight = false;
        }

        //check for scrollingLeft
        if(player.xPos <= 3 * 32)
        {

            board.setScrollingLeft(true);
            scrollingLeft = true;


        }

        if(player.xPos > 4 * 32)
        {
            board.setScrollingLeft(false);
            scrollingLeft = false;
        }

        //Make sure to not scroll everything off screen
        //stop scrolling when the left walls left side is at the ride left 
            of the screen
        if(board.gameTiles[0][0].xPos >= 0)
        {
            board.setScrollingLeft(false);
            scrollingLeft = false;
        }

        //check for collision with tiles while moving right
        if(player.movingRight == true)
        {
            for(int row = 0; row < board.gameTiles.length; row++)
            {
                for(int column = 0; column < board.gameTiles[row].length; 
                                column++)
                {
                    if((board.gameTiles[row]  
 [column].rect.contains(player.xPos + 32, player.yPos) 
|| board.gameTiles[row][column].rect.contains(player.xPos + 32, player.yPos + 31))  && 
board.gameTiles[row][column].isSolid == true)
                    {
                        player.setHitRight(true);
                    }

                    else if((board.gameTiles[row]
[column].rect.contains(player.xPos + 32, player.yPos) && board.gameTiles[row]
[column].rect.contains(player.xPos + 32, player.yPos + 31)) && board.gameTiles[row]
[column].isSolid == false)
                    {
                        player.setHitRight(false);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        //Check for collision with tiles while moving left
        if(player.movingLeft == true)
        {
            for(int row = 0; row < board.gameTiles.length; row++)
            {
                for(int column = 0; column < board.gameTiles[row].length; 
column++)
                {
                    if((board.gameTiles[row]
[column].rect.contains(player.xPos - 1, player.yPos) || board.gameTiles[row]
[column].rect.contains(player.xPos - 1, player.yPos + 31)) && board.gameTiles[row]
[column].isSolid == true)
                    {
                        player.setHitLeft(true);
                    }
                    else if((board.gameTiles[row]  
[column].rect.contains(player.xPos - 1, player.yPos) && board.gameTiles[row]
[column].rect.contains(player.xPos - 1, player.yPos + 31)) && board.gameTiles[row]
[column].isSolid == false)
                    {
                        player.setHitLeft(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //only use gravity if there is nothing solid below player       
        for(int row = 0; row < board.gameTiles.length; row++)
        {
            for(int column = 0; column < board.gameTiles[row].length; column++)
            {
                if((board.gameTiles[row][column].rect.contains(player.xPos,
 player.yPos + 32) || board.gameTiles[row][column].rect.contains(player.xPos + 31, 
 player.yPos + 32)) && board.gameTiles[row][column].isSolid == true)
                {
                    player.setGravity(false);
                }
                else if((board.gameTiles[row]
[column].rect.contains(player.xPos, player.yPos + 32) && board.gameTiles[row]
[column].rect.contains(player.xPos + 31, player.yPos + 32)) && board.gameTiles[row]
[column].isSolid == false)
                {
                    if(player.gravityOff == false)//wtf? delete?
                    {
                        player.setGravity(true);
                    }
                }

            }
        }   


        //Jumping collision
        if(player.jumping == true)
        {

            player.setHitUp(false);//Set false time every works fine - see
 commented code below

            for(int row = 0; row < board.gameTiles.length; row++)
            {
                for(int column = 0; column < board.gameTiles[row].length;
 column++)
                {
                    if((board.gameTiles[row]
[column].rect.contains(player.xPos, player.yPos - 1) || board.gameTiles[row]
[column].rect.contains(player.xPos + 31, player.yPos - 1)) && board.gameTiles[row]
[column].isSolid == true)
                    {
                        player.setHitUp(true);
                    }
//                  else if((board.gameTiles[row]
[column].rect.contains(player.xPos, player.yPos - 1) && board.gameTiles[row]
[column].rect.contains(player.xPos + 31, player.yPos - 1)) && board.gameTiles[row]
[column].isSolid == false)

//                  {
//                      player.setHitUp(false);
//                  }//couldnt get this to set false properly fixed up 
top




                }
            }
        }


    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {

        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        {

            player.setMovingRight(true);

        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A)
        {
            player.setMovingLeft(true);
        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W)
        {
            if(player.jumping == false)
            {
                if(player.gravity == false)
                {
                    player.jumping = true;
                    player.startYPos = player.yPos;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        {
            player.setMovingRight(false);

        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A)
        {
            player.setMovingLeft(false);
        }


    }


    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        //does nothing
    }

}
```

Player.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Player 
{ 
int xPos;
int yPos;
int height;
int width;
Image img1;
Image img2;
Rectangle rect;
double velocityX = 0.08;
double velocityY = 0.08;
boolean movingRight = false;
boolean movingLeft = false;
boolean hitRight = false;
boolean hitLeft = false;
boolean hitUp = false;
boolean gravity = true;
boolean jumping = false;
int startYPos;
boolean gravityOff = false;




public Player(final int xPos, final int yPos, final String img1, final String img2)
{
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.height = 32;
    this.width = 32;
    this.img1 = getImage(img1);
    this.img2 = getImage(img2);
    this.rect = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height);


}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{

    g.drawImage(img1, xPos , yPos, width, height, null);

}

public void checkForPlayerMovement(long timePassed, boolean scrollingRight, boolean     
 scrollingLeft)
{
    if(movingRight == true)
    {
        if(hitRight == false)
        {
            if(scrollingRight == false)
            {
                moveRight(timePassed);
            }
        }
    }

    if(movingLeft == true)
    {
        if(hitLeft == false)
        {
            if(scrollingLeft == false)
            {
                moveLeft(timePassed);
            }
        }
    }

    if(gravity == true)
    {
        moveDown(timePassed);
    }

    if(jumping == true)
    {

            jump(timePassed, startYPos);
    }

}

public void jump(long timepassed,int startYPos)
{   
    if(this.yPos > startYPos - 63 && hitUp == false)//63 so you cant jumpe 2 blocks but it is easier jump onto a block = level to your start pos
    {
        moveUp(timepassed);
        gravityOff = true;
    }
    else
    {
        gravity = true;
        jumping = false;
        gravityOff = false;
    }

}

public void moveRight(long timePassed)
{
    //had to change velocity manualy because moving right is slower than moving left with same velocity. WTF!
    xPos += 0.12 * timePassed;
    this.rect.x += 0.12 * timePassed;
}

public void moveLeft(long timePassed)
{
    xPos -= velocityX * timePassed;
    this.rect.x -= velocityX * timePassed;

}

public void moveDown(long timePassed)
{
    yPos += velocityY * timePassed;
    this.rect.y += velocityY * timePassed;
}

public void moveUp(long timePassed)
{
    yPos -= velocityY * timePassed;
    this.rect.y -= velocityY * timePassed;
}

public void setMovingRight(boolean moving)
{
    movingRight = moving;
}

public void setMovingLeft(boolean moving)
{
    movingLeft = moving;
}

public void setHitRight(boolean hit)
{
    hitRight = hit;
}

public void setHitLeft(boolean hit)
{
    hitLeft = hit;
}

public void setHitUp(boolean hit)
{
    hitUp = hit;
}

public void setGravity(boolean onSolid)
{
    gravity = onSolid;
}


Image getImage(String img) 
{
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(img);
}



}
```

PlayingBoard.java

```
public class PlayingBoard 
{
public Tile[][] gameTiles = new Tile[28][10];
public boolean scrollingRight = false;
public boolean scrollingLeft = false;
double velocityX = 0.05;
Player player;

public PlayingBoard(Player player)
{
    this.player = player;
    setUpBlankBoard();
}

public void setUpBlankBoard()
{
    for(int row = 0; row < gameTiles.length; row++)
    {
        for(int column = 0; column < gameTiles[row].length; column++)
        {
            gameTiles[row][column] = new Tile(row * 32, column * 32 + 24, 0);
        }

    }

}

public void checkForScroll(long timePassed)
{
    if(scrollingRight == true)
    {
        if(player.movingRight == true)
        {
            if(player.hitRight == false)
            {
                scrollRight(timePassed);
            }
        }
    }

    if(scrollingLeft == true)
    {
        if(player.movingLeft == true)
        {
            if(player.hitLeft == false)
            {
                scrollLeft(timePassed);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void scrollRight(long timePassed)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < gameTiles.length; row++)
    {
        for(int column = 0; column < gameTiles[row].length; column++)
        {
            gameTiles[row][column].xPos -= velocityX * timePassed;
            gameTiles[row][column].rect.x -= velocityX * timePassed;

        }

    }
}

public void scrollLeft(long timePassed)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < gameTiles.length; row++)
    {
        for(int column = 0; column < gameTiles[row].length; column++)
        {
            gameTiles[row][column].xPos += velocityX * timePassed;
            gameTiles[row][column].rect.x += velocityX * timePassed;

        }

    }
}

public void setScrollingRight(boolean scrolling)
{
    scrollingRight = scrolling;
}

public void setScrollingLeft(boolean scrolling)
{
    scrollingLeft = scrolling;
}

}
```

Tile.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class Tile 
{
int xPos;
int yPos;
int height;
int width;
boolean isSolid = false;
boolean isHazard = false;
boolean isDeadly = false;
Image img1;
Rectangle rect;
int tileType;


public Tile(final int xPos, final int yPos, final int tileType)
{
    this.tileType = tileType;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    width = 32;
    height = 32;
    this.rect =  new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height);
    defineTile();

}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    if(tileType != 0)
    {   
        g.drawImage(img1, xPos, yPos, width, height, null); 

    }

}

public void defineTile()
{
    if(tileType == 0)
    {
        blankTile();
    }
    if(tileType == 1)
    {
        groundTile();
    }
}

public void groundTile()
{
    img1 = getImage("images/ground.png");
    isSolid = true;

}

public void blankTile()
{

}

public void setTileType(int type)
{
    tileType = type;
    defineTile();
}




Image getImage(String img) 
{
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(img);
}


}
```

ReadLevelFile.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ReadLevelFile 
{
Scanner input;
int column = 0;
int row = 0;
public void openFile()
{
    try
    {
        input = new Scanner(new File("level1.txt"));
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}

public void readFile(PlayingBoard board)
{

    for(int column = 0; column < board.gameTiles[column].length; column++)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row < board.gameTiles.length; row++)
        {
            int x = input.nextInt();
            board.gameTiles[row][column].setTileType(x);
        }

    }
}

public void closeFile()
{
    input.close();
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be messing with the tile positions when the camera scrolls. These should be relatively immutable. Use an offset which is used in drawing calculations instead.

Comment: Thanks Chris. That makes a lot of sense I'm not sure how to do it though. I'll see If I can figure it out.

Comment: I don't think I understand. What I tried to do was instead of moving the rectangle of the tiles I was only displaying the tiles and the player as if they were scrolling. Is this the wrong idea or did I just not code it properly?

Comment: Only if you used a sprite framework, and even then the sprites would be movable as a group (using the group offset). You should just worry about the camera, and how to draw in relation to the camera.

Answer (score 0):

There are packages that do this type of stuff-- you really need one!

I would post a question about what a good 2D game framework is.

Good luck.

Comment: This seems to be more of a comment that an answer.

Comment: Ok, next time i will use a comment :)

Comment: My understanding of a framework is something that is already done and I just use, witch is not what I'm looking for thanks anyway. If I'm wrong please let me know.